# Unable to import some variables from django settings

Tags: python, django

I have set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to be my settings file. 
Some sample lines of this settings file follow:

```
TEST = {
    'CLIENT': os.environ.get("CLIENT_NAME", "unknown"),
    'ENVIRONMENT': os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT", "unknown")
}

client = os.environ.get("CLIENT_NAME", "unknown")
environment = os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT", "unknown")
```

I then try to import the django settings by using

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
```

I am then able to print the value of the `django_settings.TEST['CLIENT']` but not of the `django_settings.client` as I get `'Settings' object has no attribute 'client'`

What am I missing? To my the only difference is that TEST is a dict while client is a variable of string type.

Comment: You don't have `client` variable declared. You do have instead `client_name`

Comment: Shouldn't this be `django_settings.client_name`? (so `client_name` instead of `client`)?

Comment: Note that you made a typo (`ENVIROMENT` -> `ENVIRONMENT`).

Comment: Sorry guys, both are typos that I made here. The actual code has no typos

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I checked it a million times and also I wouldn't be able to use `django_settings.TEST['CLIENT']` otherwise. Is there a chance that it has to do with the fact that client is not capitalized? I have seen no such reference but I am out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed because settings must be in all capitals. This is specified in [the settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings):

> There’s nothing stopping you from creating your own settings, for your own Django apps. Just follow these guidelines:
>
> - Setting names must be all uppercase.

Behind the scenes, this is because `django.conf.settings` is not actually a module but a class that is dynamically created based on that module; [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py#L136) only reads variables that are in all caps.

(Note also that stylistically, this makes sense; settings by definition are constants, and Python style is to put constants in all caps.)